# Copy and paste only non n#a cells in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

How do i copy and paste column data A to column B without #N/A data.

I have data in a column A

```
A          B

8a61     8a61
#N/A      fs
fs       fttt
fttt     dsff
#N/A
dsff
```

To copy paste non blank cells i used

```
  Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Sheet7")
  ws1.Range("A1:A1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy  ws1.Range("B1")
```

How do i copy paste column data without #N/A

Comment: Create a loop to check the cell contents and move them over if they are not #N/A.

Comment: Or filter column A to exclude `#N/A` and then do the copy.

Comment: Or copy the whole lot and then delete from the copy special cells formula errors (assuming you don't have other errors you want to keep).

Comment: Actually, guessing these are not formula errors otherwise your original code would have worked so I think the others methods proposed would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, will obviously need putting in a sub()

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 1
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
If Not IsError(Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
    Cells(j, 4) = Cells(i, 1)
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim rng As Range
    Dim crange As Range
    Dim lastrow As Double

```
Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False

Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set crange = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"

crange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("b2")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.